# Deploy telegram with webhook

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm more than a day look how to deploy telegram bot with webhook instead of polling..

even in the official doc it's not work for me https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks

someone can explain me oh give me some link to work tutorial  how to deploy the most basic bot like this one

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')


def help_command(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')


def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


def main():

    TOKEN = "telegramToken"

    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))
    PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))
    SERVER = 'myipserver/'
    CERT = 'cert.pem'
    updater.bot.setWebhook(SERVER + TOKEN, certificate=open(CERT, 'rb'))
    # updater.bot.setWebhook(SERVER + TOKEN) also dont working
    updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0", port=PORT, url_path=TOKEN)

    # updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default port in App Engine is 8080
And the webhook in telegram does not support this port (just ports 443, 80, 88, or 8443)
https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks

Answer (score -1):

I run my Telegram BOTs on Heroku and normally start the webhook then is set it:

```
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                      port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)),
                      url_path='token'
updater.bot.setWebhook("https://myapp.com/token")

updater.idle()
```

When deploying on Heroku you get a URL for your application using SSL (https://myapp.herokuapp.com), which you then configure via the BotFather.

Providing the BotFather with a HTTPS url is a must, I wonder if you don't do that or maybe there is an issue with the SSL certificate you are using (self-signed?)

Comment: I want to deploy it on google cloud..
I don't want to deploy it heroku..
I put there my ip instance and open port 5000 in firewall rule

Comment: Thats fine, I am trying to help to give you a real example, you should be able to follow the same approach and deploy on any cloud provider. You should add a test URL to your chatbot (adding maybe Flask) to confirm you can reach the application using HTTPS